# Found bug using Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Recently I used the Apache RewriteEngine (mod-rewrite) to try rewriting this file:

```
api.access.php
```

to this directory:

```
/api
```

using this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^api$ api.access.php [L,QSA]
```

but it kept failing.

Oddly, replacing `/api` with some other string like `/apis` worked. So what was the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually that is not really a bug. Apache is pretty well tested for a long time. What you're **probably** running into is `content Negotiation` and `MultiViews.` It might be causing some funny business.

So your answer really won't help anyone because changing the file name is not a solution. You probably just needed to disable `MultiViews`.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api/?$ api.access.php [L,QSA]
```

More on [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html)

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a
>   request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and
>   /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory
>   looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map
>   which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and
>   content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of
>   them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's
>   requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the name of the file I was trying to replace (`api.access.php`), because it started with `api`.

Changing the filename to `access.api.php` fixed it.

Hope this is of use to anyone out there.

Cheers